# Extra argument 'error' in call

Tags: swift, swift2

I have this error on this piece of code, could any one tell me how can I change the this in Swift 2.0

```
if jsonResponse != nil {
  propertyListResponse = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonResponse, 
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves,
    error: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove error in the paramater list

```
if jsonResponse != nil { propertyListResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( jsonResponse, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves ) 
...
catch let error as NSError {
    // error handling
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: if jsonResponse != nil {
                    propertyListResponse =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
                        jsonResponse,
                        options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves)

Comment: Now I have this error: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Comment: check now updated answer. if an error occur then it throws that error so we need to handle that error with try catch.

Comment: Problem solve thanks, this link is helpful too:     https://gist.github.com/awaxman11/9c48c0b4c622bffb879f